CUDA Exception in `TrainEvalCallback` while training a tabular neural network
This is the code I'm trying to run, it is based on the "tabular" chapter of FastAI's book. Though process looks the same and all outputs from blocks look correct, my code doesn't work.
df_nn = pd.read_excel(path)

dep_var = 'label'
label_order = 'mauvais', 'moyen', 'bon'

df_nn_final = df_nn.drop('Ref', axis=1)
df_nn_final['label'] = df_nn_final['label'].astype('category')
df_nn_final['label'] = df_nn_final['label'].cat.set_categories(label_order, ordered=True)

df_nn_final.head()

which prints :
patch_number patch_25mm2_number patch_sizes_mean patch_sizes_max patch_aeral_rate label
0   79  2   4.99    124.60  0.111   bon
1   225 11  5.12    46.07   0.280   bon
2   153 6   5.52    129.10  0.255   moyen
3   26  2   7.81    47.74   0.046   bon
4   321 2   3.47    31.00   0.250   bon

cont_nn,cat_nn = cont_cat_split(df_nn_final, max_card=10, dep_var=dep_var)

procs_nn = [Categorify, Normalize]
to_nn = TabularPandas(df_nn_final, 
                      procs_nn, 
                      cat_names=cat_nn, 
                      cont_names=cont_nn, 
                      splits=RandomSplitter(0.2)(range_of(df_nn_final)), 
                      y_names=dep_var)

to_nn.valid

Which prints :
   patch_number  patch_25mm2_number  patch_sizes_mean  patch_sizes_max  \
6     -0.305786           -0.776085         -1.140347        -0.804915   
8      1.729851            1.656420          0.671621        19.049810   
7      5.319975            1.818587         -0.833369        -0.359075   

   patch_aeral_rate  label  
6         -0.885082      2  
8          7.236846      0  
7          2.030482      0  

Which is exactly what it should look like, categorical variables are embedded correctly.
dls = to_nn.dataloaders(batch_size=2)

learn = tabular_learner(dls, layers=[200, 100], n_out=3, loss_func=F.cross_entropy)
learn.lr_find()

And there is where I get the error :
RuntimeError: Exception occured in `TrainEvalCallback` when calling event `before_fit`:
    CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

I tried to look up what this error could be, tried processing the code on CPU as it should give a better understanding of what causes the error.
It seems like a shape mismatch between tensors, but I have been looking for several hours printing every variable and I can't find something that would cause it. Which is frustrating because it looks like a very simple application.
